# Compute Engine Istance group gcloud - IP change if a specific istance go down

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, autoscaling

I have a huge problem with the manage of an istance group on gcloud compute engine.

I setting to the 1st istance of the group a static ip XX.XXX.XX.XX, this ip is connected with a Domain.

If during the scaling the first machine created was canceled, no one of the new instances will take that IP.
This is a problem because my domain go down.
I thinked to manage this by creating another separeted istance that ping the domain...and if the domain is down change (with gcloud commands) the ip of one that new istances.

I want to ask, there is someone that had found some trick to solve this issue? 
Thank's guys

EDIT: Ok, LB is working, but I need to "live streaming" through that LB because this LB manage an istance group that manage the live streaming.
Now, if I set it, I can't go live (from any software, such OBS and similar) :/

So, a little recap:
I have my domain `example.com`
I have my istance group `istance_group_example`
Load balancer `http_loadb`
I set on the frontend of http_loadb my ip (static, not temp), then I go to cloudflare and set the static ip.
If i go to my example.com, i can see my custom page.

Now the problem is, i can access to server, but if I need to create a live streaming with OBS (for example), obs just load the connection for a while but then stop.

If i point my DNS directly to the IP of an istance inside istance group (bypassing the load balancer) everything works.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you actually are looking for is an [HTTP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) . The load balancer should take the static IP where your domain is pointing to. Form there it can forward the traffic to any instances that are in a healthy status at the moment (another thing you are looking for are [health checks](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks) which more or less do what you set up with the other instance group, and ping (for TCP) or execute GET/HEAD requests regularly and, if any instance is unresponsive, it gets taken care of and receives no traffic until recovered).

So, the base architecture of your solution would be like this:

- One managed instance group set to autoscale (if you need it) and autohealing (pretty much mandatory in this case, so any dead instance gets replaced by a healthy one).
- A health check set up on the **instance group** that will keep polling the instances on the "servie port" to confirm if they are UP or not. [This is important to ensure that the instances are checked consistently and terminated/recreated based on a consistent metric](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#monitoring_groups). The load balancer will use it's own health check too.
- A global HTTP loead balancer (Network services -> load balancer -> HTTP(S) Load Balancer) pointing to a backend service that you will create. The backend service will point to your instance group and to the relevant ports for your service. Assign another health check here. This will be useful so the LB is aware as soon as one instance fails so it can take it out of the pool of destinations. If you don't specifically need it don't select session affinity.
- For the LB frontend select HTTP(S) port(s) or anything you need, then under IP address select "create new static address" and name it. This IP address will be where your DNS records for your domain should be pointing at.
- After the LB is ready get to your nameservers (like CloudDNS if you are managing your domain DNS from there, if not to whatever solution your registrar provides) and point the A record to the IP you assigned to the load balancer.

Comment: Ohhhh ok!
So i have this Domain --> https://example.com
I have the istance group --> istance-group-scalable

I need to create this load balancer (i suppose in backend, that istances doesn't cover frontend application) and add to Cloud DNS my domain?

Comment: OK, I will be updating my answer for clarity instead of cluttering the comments. Take a look.

Comment: Question updated, maybe I have to set a TCP load balancer?

Comment: OK,if you are not actually serving HTTP traffic yes, you probably need a TCP load balancer. On top of this, I think that the issue you are having is probably a connection timeout  (even if the connection is not actually inactive if the load balancer doesn't receive traffic from the client it drops it). For TCP load balancers the timeout is 10 minute, much longer than HTTP so maybe that works for you. If not you probably should look into sending periodic "keepalives". More about that here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/8knQumfLsBY

Comment: What if i need to serve both: HTTP(S) and TCP?

Comment: No way to put a "proxy" with an IP on my managed compute engine and external? Or load balancer to grab both HTTP and TCP requests?

Comment: In response to your latest question, If you need to serve both HTTP and TCP traffic, you wouldn't be able to use a HTTPS load balance a for both of these requirements (a HTTPS load balancer can deal with HTTP/HTTPS only). You could use two load balancer (a HTTP(S) and a TCP). Or you could us a network load balancer, and have two separate frontends (one for traffic on port 80, on for traffic on another port), although this would mean you still have to use two separate frontend IP addresses for the load balancer.